# How to create a Dynamic decodeResource?

Tags: android

I want to create a dynamic decodeResource to use very images in the object.

This is my code:

```
for(int i=42; i<55; i++) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    Integer.parseInt("R.drawable.a"+i));
        }
```

I want to get the files

```
R.drawable.a43 to a54
```

Its possible to create a loop for decodeResource?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the resource ID for 'R.drawable.a##' dynamically we can use [`Resources.getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) as follows:

```
final String pkg = context.getPackageName();
final Resources resources = context.getResources();
...
int num = ...; /* between 43 and 54 */
final int id = resources.getIdentifier("a" + num, "drawable", pkg);
```

You can store these in a `List` using a loop much like the one you have now, only with slightly modified bounds:

```
final String pkg = context.getPackageName();
final Resources resources = context.getResources();

final List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
for (int i = 43; i <= 54; ++i) {
  /* decode bitmap with id R.drawable.a{i} */
  final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
      resources.getIdentifier("a" + i, "drawable", pkg));
  bitmaps.add(bitmap);
}
/* now bitmaps contains the Bitmaps */
```